# Place to write laravel RAW queries?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We are currently working with a big laravel 5.2 project. For our query, we always try to use Eloquent ORM. But sometimes we need to use RAW queries.

We think in future, we have to write more RAW queries. So we need a separate place and a well-organised way to write RAW queries.We don’t want to write raw query in our controller and model.

Is there any other place where we can put raw queries. Or what is the best procedure to write raw queries(Write a separate file or repository etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes)

For each group of related queries, I would create a file in scopes directory structured according to your models structure.

This will give you a central place where you could add or edit your raw queries.

Comment: The purpose of our query is little more difference then query scope. Our necessary query is little more complex (multiple joining).